# Magento2 Module installable through composer

Tags: magento2, composer, marketplace

We are in the middle of the process to submit an extension to the Magento Marketplace. 
We have one question about composer installation.
Right now, we test our module copying files by hand, is it mandatory to make the module installable using composer? 
Once our module is on Magento Marketplace, are they going to host the repo files on their composer repository, or should we create a private repo to host the module's files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now, we test our module copying files by hand, is it mandatory to make the module installable using composer?

yes. When you buy an extension on the marketplace, you can install it via the repo.magento.com composer repository with your authentication keys.

> Once our module is on Magento Marketplace, are they going to host the repo files on their composer repository, or should we create a private repo to host the module's files?

See above. You don't need to create your own composer repository.

Answer (score 1):

Importance of `composer.json` file might be underestimated. Every single Magento 2 module, package, theme and localization should include composer.json file with all dependencies listed.

I saw a lot of Magento 2 modules where only 1 dependency listed which is “magento/framework”. This is incorrect assumption to have dependency only for Framework if your module uses `Magento\Catalog\Api` interfaces from “magento/module-catalog” package for example.

Use this guide how to build quality Magento module: https://medium.com/@maxpronko/10-practical-rules-to-build-high-quality-magento-2-module-e6fe2c9461ac